# How to list resources when using remote state?

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform 0.12.9 and state is saved on s3 bucket. I'd like to list all resources by `terraform state list`. Based on this document, https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/list.html, it says `-state=path - Path to the state file. Defaults to "terraform.tfstate". Ignored when remote state is used.`. How can I pass the state file if it is on remote s3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the tfstate bucket path in your `terraform.tf` file:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "bucket_name"
    key    = "my/key/location/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "bucket region"
  }
}
```

and later you need to run `terraform init` so that terraform would fetch the state from the remote bucket

Comment: I have this file saved in `.terraform/terraform.tfstate` file. How can I run `terraform init` to fetch the remote state?

Comment: The `.tfstate` file was created using some terraform config (`.tf` file/s), and they are strongly related. If you don't have the config file/s You can try to reproduce it from the `.tfstate` file but it's not an easy task.

Basically after having the `.tf` file/s you need to run `terraform init` in the directory the main `.tf` file is located.

Comment: If I download remote resources to local, can I use `terraform state rm` to remove remote resources?

Comment: I am not sure, but if you create an empty `terraform.tf` file and use your downloaded state, it will probably work. because terraform will see a state full of resources and a config with no resources, and running `terrafrom apply` will change the state to a state with no resources

Answer (score 0):

1. `terraform init`
2. `terraform workspace list` # show all workspaces
3. `terraform workspace select {env}` # select the workspace which you want list resources
4. `terraform state list` # list all resources. Could return nothing if there is no resource in the workspace
5. `terraform state show '{resource}'` # show the attributes of a single resource